# How to show uncommitted changes in Git and some Git diffs in detail

Tags: git, git-diff

How do I show uncommitted changes in Git?

I [STFW'ed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/STFW#Verb), and these commands are not working:

```
teyan@TEYAN-THINK MINGW64 /d/nano/repos/PSTools/psservice (teyan/psservice)
$ git status
On branch teyan/psservice
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/teyan/psservice'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   psservice.c
        modified:   psservice.vcxproj.filters


teyan@TEYAN-THINK MINGW64 /d/nano/repos/PSTools/psservice (teyan/psservice)
$ git diff

teyan@TEYAN-THINK MINGW64 /d/nano/repos/PSTools/psservice (teyan/psservice)
$ git diff master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 638, accepted):

> ***How to show uncommitted changes in Git***

The command you are looking for is [***`git diff`***](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

> ***`git diff`*** - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc

---

Here are some of the options it expose which you can use

***`git diff`*** (no parameters)
Print out differences between your working directory and the index.

***`git diff --cached`***:
Print out differences between the **index** and HEAD (current commit).

***`git diff HEAD`***:
Print out differences between your **working directory** and the HEAD.

***`git diff --name-only`***
Show only names of changed files.

***`git diff --name-status`***
Show only **names and status** of changed files.

***`git diff --color-words`***
Word by word diff instead of line by line.

Here is a sample of the output for `git diff --color-words`:

[image]

Comment: When you see the colon prompt at the end, it means git has shown the first page - press enter to step through the other changes (like you can with cat file | more)

Comment: --staged and --cached are synonyms

Comment: For completeness I would include 
git diff dev..origin/dev

Comment: It's important to note, that you need to type `HEAD` all in capitals. I tried to use `Head` and it failed.

Comment: @CodeWizard what style of documentation did you use? I find it very effective and would love to learn how to replicate.

Comment: Edit the comment and you can see the source @albvar

Answer (score 64):

You have already staged the changes (presumably by running `git add`), so in order to get their diff, you need to run:

```
git diff --cached
```

(A plain `git diff` will only show unstaged changes.)

For example:
[image: Example git diff cached use]

Answer (score 10):

For me, the only thing which worked is

```
git diff HEAD
```

including the staged files, `git diff --cached` only shows staged files.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not the right way to show uncommitted files, but it works:
`git switch <current-branch>`

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation of `git status` showing changes, but `git diff` printing nothing, although there were changes in several lines. However:

```
$ git diff data.txt > myfile
$ cat myfile
<prints diff>
```

Git 2.20.1 on raspbian. Other commands like `git checkout`, `git pull` are printing to stdout without problems.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

- *[Reference image **( PS screen shot )**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4KP.png)*

  - Image Key

    | Shape Color | Command / Description |
    | --- | --- |
    | Red | `git status` |
    | Yellow | `git status -b -s` |
    | Purple | PowerShell modules `posh-git` and `posh-with` functionality |
- Troubleshooting `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master'`

  - `git pull; git branch -a`

    - Pulls down latest copy of repo, lists all branches in repo

      - Issue likely caused by 2 branches ( local and remote ) both named master, but neither is specified in `git diff` command
- *Show uncommitted changes* : `git status`

  - **Example** command output shown in [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4KP.png)

    - `git status` : **RED** rectangle
    - `git status -b -s` : **YELLOW** rectangle

      - `-b` shows working branch and target branch info
      - `-s` is for short output
    - Additional [`git status` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)
- PS, aka PowerShell

  - `posh-git` and `posh-with` modules : **PURPLE** rectangle / **CYAN** branch data

    ```
    # PowerShell Module Imports
    Import-Module posh-git   # install before usable | Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
    Import-Module posh-with  # install before usable | Install-Module posh-with -Scope CurrentUser
    ```

    - **NOTE:** Modules can be installed **without admin privileges** (`-Scope currentUser`)

#### Reference Image Key

---

... Apologies in advance if this is too much detail...

### 1. The Error message

- `ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`

  - Pretty sure this means that the local repo doesn't know about the branch `master`

    - Try `git pull; git branch -a`
    - This will pull the latest copy of the remote repo and display all local and remote branches on the terminal

      - If the branch was created on the git website or gui, the local repo may not know about the newly created branch

### 2. Showing uncommitted changes in Git

There are any number of ways to check uncommitted changes, but I will focus on doing so in PowerShell from the **cmd**

- `git status`

  - This command in **PS** *(or really any shell)* will show many things such as:

    - changed but uncommitted files
    - files that will be committed on next commit
    - untracked files on local machine/branch
  - the additional flags/options may be added on to the command, such as `-b` to show branch information, and `-s` to shorten the output

## 3. PowerShell

I use **PowerShell** at work as our team has a decent amount of PS code, but this process should be applicable to most shells (with some instruction tweaking)

Two very useful Modules are available for PowerShell: `posh-git` and `posh-with`

```
# PowerShell Module Imports
Import-Module posh-git   # install before usable | Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Module posh-with  # install before usable | Install-Module posh-with -Scope CurrentUser
```

- These modules may be installed for only the currentUser *(no admin rights!)*
- Once installed, the modules may be added to `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

  - If added to the above file *(PowerShell User Profile)*, the modules are imported at the beginning of every PS session

---

## [ORIGINAL COMMENT]

- `git status`

  - shows file changes, files to be committed, untracked files, etc.
- **error message**

  - appears to be caused by local and remote branches with same name, but not specifying which branch
- powershell

  - if using powershell, there are 2 modules that can be installed for **currentUser** and make working with git from the command line much easier

    ```
    # PowerShell Module Imports
    Import-Module posh-git   # install before usable | Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
    Import-Module posh-with  # install before usable | Install-Module posh-with -Scope CurrentUser
    ```

#### [Reference image (*powershell screen shot*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4KP.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

[image]

You can goto Visual Studio Control. Click on Source Control on the left hand side. it will show all uncommitted changes.