# Get new and modified (real status) file by git

Tags: linux, git, file, version-control

## My Situation

I want to get new and modified files and then do something such as `compress`.Out of consideration to `efficacy`, I can not search all files every time. So `git` comes into my mind.

I know `git status` can help me to get all changed files and then I can filter them by myself.But there is a problem.Let me hold an example.

I have a file named `text.txt` whose content is `Hello`. Then I modified its content to `Hello World`.Now I execute `git add test.txt`. Finally I recover its content to `Hello`.

- If this time I also execute`git add test.txt`, then `git status` gives me nothing.It's right because in fact the file not modified.
- If this time I do not, the `git status` shows

> Changes to be committed:
>       modified:   test.txt
>
> Changes not staged for commit:
>       modified:   test.txt

## My Question

Is there any way to do such thing by `git`?

## Edit

Maybe `git` does not work in this situation.So is there other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The direct answer is no.**

The mechanism for git to track uncommitted changes as below:

[image]

> Git has three main states that your files can reside in: committed,
>   modified, and staged. Committed means that the data is safely stored
>   in your local database. Modified means that you have changed the file
>   but have not committed it to your database yet. Staged means that you
>   have marked a modified file in its current version to go into your
>   next commit snapshot.

More details, you can refer [Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

**Changes not staged for commit:** that list the files with modified states.

**Changes to be committed:** list the files which are staged and waiting for record the staged file to next commit.

- For the second operation as you tried (use `git status` directly), it’s caused by you changed the connect of `test.txt` to `Hello World` and stage this file for the first time. So there has the status `Changes to be committed: modified: test.txt`. When you changed the content `test.txt` back (`Hello`), there also has a modified state (compared working directory with staged version) for `test.txt` `Changes not staged for commit: modified: test.txt`.
- For the first operation you tried (use `git add test.txt` for the second time), when you staged the changed content `Hello` for the second time, git can detected there is no changed between the stage version and the current committed version (compare between staged version and the current version in `.git` folder). So git will shows `nothing to commit, working tree clea`n.

**In a word**, if you change a file with multiple times while uncommitted during the time, git will not track uncommitted changes.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. So `git` does not work for me in this situation. Do you know other way?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Git truly doesn't meet your situation. As far as I know, all the VCS (Version control system) are compare the last uncommitted version with the current version. The work around is commit each time changes if you want to track all changed version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

use `git diff` to show differences between a commits, your work folder, etc.

for reference:

[git diff documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

[Excellent answer to related question here on SO that goes into more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978550/git-how-to-show-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: I just want to know the file name rather the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about your needs, but if you just want a compact list of the modified files, you can try:

> git status -s

that will returns:

> MM text.txt

the first "M" stands for "Changes to be committed", the seconds "M" stands for "Changes not staged for commit".

Comment: Can I get what real status of the file ?

Comment: Nope, not in an easy way.
A way may be to check the file only in the "Changes to be committed" area, but to have consistent results, needs you to perform a `git add filename` everytime before to check the file status with `git status`