# git push rejected, maybe because of rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have an automated Jenkins job which simply does the following:

- pull from `remoteA`
- push into `remoteB`

`remoteA` is the remote where developers actually push their code.

`remoteB` is never touched manually, it only receives udates trough that automated Job.

It worked well for a while, but now I get `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.` when trying to push into `remoteB`

As far as I know, this happens when

- (a) `remoteB` contains changes which `remoteA` doesn't contain -> I think that's not possible because no human and no other Jenkins Job touches remoteB
- (b) someone did a `rebase` on remoteA. -> As I am no git professional, I am very unsure how to deal with that scenario. Hope someone here can help.

Comment: in this scenario try `git pull --rebase remoteB remoteA` and then try to run job again.

NOTE: check the log and verify the commits before proceeding

Comment: It might be a good idea to see the changes in the branches `remoteA` and `remoteB` and to see what's different (do this with `git fetch origin/remoteB && git diff remoteA..origin/remoteB`. You can also check the `remoteA` history and check if it has strange changes to it. As to how to fix the problem, you cat either whip-out the bazooka and `git push -f origin remoteB` or do a `git pull --rebase remoteB remoteA` and then push to B

Comment: Just to explicitly confirm your assuption at the end, yes, (b) is the almost certain scenario here.

Comment: Yes, the only reason is that someone rewrote the history already pushed (with a `rebase` or an `amend`). And you can only solve your problem with a `git push --force-with-lease` (if you want to keep the 'new' git history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did a `rebase` which modified the history so you cannot push to the remote unless you wish to **overwrite** and **change** the content of your repository.

If you still wish to push the content you must use the `-f`

```
# FORCE overwrite of old content with the new result of you rebase 
git push -f
```

---

In your case that the content is handled by Jenkins, a rebase can be a good reason to why it stopped working.

---

#### How to find out if there was a rebase

Check the diff between the 2 branches (local vs remote)

```
# fetch all remotes if you have multiple ones
git fetch --all

# check the diff between the 2 branches (2 ..)
git diff localBranch..origin/remoteBranch


# check the diff between the 2 branches (3 ..)
git diff localBranch...origin/remoteBranch
```

you can read more about git diff
[How to show uncommitted changes in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978550/how-to-show-uncommitted-changes-in-git/35978722#35978722)

Comment: `--force` did the trick. Now history of both remotes look identical (that was my goal). Thank you!